# VSTO and html body in outlook mailitem

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, html-email, office-addins

I am currently working on a VSTO project and modifying the HTML content of a mailItem (HTMLBody).

After modification, the original HTML + mod is then converted to the infamous WORD HTML (with loads of MSO tags..)

Is is possible that if you modify & save the mailItem, it preserves the original HTML formatting ?

Thanks a lot for any pointers,

Comment: You need to be more specific than that - when does the HTML body get converted? When you modify it (what is your code)? Or after Outlook displays the message?

Comment: I need to rework on this, the code inserts a HTML tag in the body, but the MSO conversion seems to appears only in some cases (I am not completely sure yet)

Comment: As a general rule, don't expect custom tags to survive when handled by Outlook - it uses Word-light to display HTML, which is converted to its native format and back.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering the HTML markup of message bodies. Whatever you put to the message body MS Word evaluates and applies its own business rules to the markup because it needs to make sure it is well-formed and etc. If you need to put any custom information consider using custom properties of Outlook items.